# How to read file from assets folder synchronously (without await) using flutter

Tags: file, flutter, dart

I need to read simple json file synchronously from assets folder.
I have made a function which is doing what I need:

```
Future<void> init() async {
    _charList = jsonDecode(await rootBundle.loadString('assets/ble_db/characteristic_uuids.json'));
    _servicesList = jsonDecode(await rootBundle.loadString('assets/ble_db/service_uuids.json'));        
  }
```

But the only problem of this aproach is async behaviour. For my program it would be much better if it would be a blocking code which i could call from normal function.

When I am trying to use this approach:

```
var config = new File('./assets/ble_db/service_uuids.json');
var str = config.readAsStringSync();
```

I am getting an error

```
Cannot open file, path = './assets/ble_db/service_uuids.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

How could i read file from assets folder synchronously?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: I started learning flutter for convenience, but its only creates more problems

Answer (score -1):

1. did you add this in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/ble_db/
```

2. make the path like this

```
var config = new File('assets/ble_db/service_uuids.json');
```

Comment: You can't load assets with "File" afaik.